# how to find if two verilog modules are connected using VPI PLI - Verilog VCS

Tags: verilog, hdl

```
module A (
    output A_OPORT_1 
    ); 
endmodule

module B (
    input B_IPORT_1
    ); 
endmodule

module TestBench;
wire A_to_B; 
A A_inst (
        .A_OPORT_1  (A_to_B)
        );
B B_inst (
        .B_IPORT_1  (A_to_B)
        );

endmodule
```

Here basically output port A:A_inst:A_OPORT_1 is connected to B:B_inst:B_IPORT_1

How can I retrieve that information using a verilog PLI? Example appreciated.

I have some code that gets a port and retrieves the highconn and is able to get the wire/net A_to_B.

However I am not able to find out what ports are connected to A_To_B using vpiPortInst. I get an iterator that is null.

```
    vpiHandle high = vpi_handle(vpiHighConn, port); 
        vpi_printf(" High conndata type is %s\n",
            vpi_get_str(vpiType, high));
        vpi_printf(" High conndata Net type is %s\n",
            vpi_get_str(vpiNetType, high));                    
        vpi_printf(" High conndata Name is %s\n",
            vpi_get_str(vpiFullName, high));     

        vpiHandle iter = vpi_iterate(vpiPortInst,high);
        vpiHandle p2ref;
        if (iter == NULL)
        {
            vpi_printf(" Port Iterator is null\n");                      
        }
```

O/P:

```
 High conndata type is vpiNet
 High conndata Net type is vpiWire
 High conndata Name is $unit::A_to_B
 Port Iterator is null
```

Comment: In your code, those 2 ports are not connected together because `A_inst` and `B_Inst` are in separate Tb modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code works. As toolic pointed out the two ports have to be connected.

Now this works and I'm able to print out the fan outs.